# ruby-on-rails override state_machine in the inherited class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, state-machine

I have two ActiveRecord classes:

```
class Gateway::Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  state_machine :initial => :setup do
   # ... many events..
  end
end
```

and an inherited class

```
class Gateway::BetterTransaction < Gateway::Transaction
  state_machine :initial => :setup do
    # ... many events ...
  end
end
```

The problem is that all the events and rules from the base class are still in the inherited class.

I looked in the [`state_machine`](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem documentation and saw no option of how to modify this behavior - only that if a transition exists (also in the base class) then the state machine will use the first found transition.

Is there a way to override the state machine from the base class with a new one?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't override the whole state machine? Can you override just some methods? If these two models has so different behaviour maybe they shouldn't be linked with inheritance?

Comment: I want them to be linked with inheritance (their ORM is the same). Of course , I can do it otherwise, but it will be ugly and create many lines of duplicate code.

Comment: I would suggest moving the shared logic up and out into a new superclass (like `Gateway::BaseTransaction`), which both `Transaction` and `BetterTransaction` extend. Then the two calls to state_machine won't interfere with each other.

Comment: @gmcnaughton your solution is neat, and that was my alternative solution, but it still requires many changes in my project. What I'm really looking is a  way to just override the state machine.